# webNavigation.onDOMContentLoaded URL filter does not match DNS error URL

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

Reference to the answer for my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44529667/injecting-into-navigation-error-page-gets-error-no-window-matching-matchesho/44532808?noredirect=1#). Briefly: When an error occurs in a navigation `webRequest` (e.g. a DNS lookup error), the URL to which the tab navigates is available in the `url` property of `webNavigation.onDOMContentLoaded` event for the navigation to the displayed error page, but the *actual* URL displayed (i.e. the `about:neterror` URL) is not available through other means.

I want to follow the answer's method for getting the error page URL. I wrote this example code where I receive an error page in the browser but when I use `webNavigation.onDOMContentLoaded` to get the actual URL for the error, the code returns nothing at all. Note that, the code returns the correct URL if there is no error.

Here is my example (*test.js*):

```
var filter = {
  url:
  [
    {hostContains: "pagedoesnotexist.com"}
  ]
}

function logOnDOMContentLoaded(details) {
  console.log("onDOMContentLoaded: " + details.url);
}

browser.webNavigation.onDOMContentLoaded.addListener(logOnDOMContentLoaded, filter);
```

And, the *manifest.json*

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "test
  "version": "1.0",
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["test.js"]
  },
  "permissions": [
    "<all_urls>",
    "activeTab",
    "tabs",
    "storage",
    "webRequest",
    "webNavigation"
  ] 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code does not work the way you desire, because the URL you are looking for does not contain `pagedoesnotexist.com` as part of the host. The URL on which the error occurred is part of the [query](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier#Syntax), not the host.

Unfortunately, using the [events.UrlFilter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/events/UrlFilter) key `queryContains` appears to have bugs (I'm still looking into the behavior I'm seeing).  I found the following modifications to your code to be effective:

```js
var errorDomain = 'pagedoesnotexist.com';
var filter = {
  url:
  [
    //{urlPrefix: 'about:neterror'} // works
    // The simple RegExps in the following urlMatches have the
    // possibility to produce false positives on matching the
    // domain.  In other words, some other error URLs could match
    // this RegExp.  However, a more complex RegExp which would
    // prevent such false positive matches would depend on the
    // exact criteria you desire to use for matching.  For
    // instance, are you wanting to match sub-domains?  Only HTTP? 
    // both HTTP and HTTPS?  Any protocol (e.g.  FTP)?
    {urlMatches: '^about:neterror\\?.*' + errorDomain + '.*'} // works.
    //{urlMatches: '.*pagedoesnotexist.com.*'} // works
    //{urlMatches: '.*page.*'} // works
    //{queryContains: 'pagedoesnotexist.com'} // Does NOT work (potentially a Firefox bug)
    //{queryContains: 'page'} // Does NOT work (potentially a Firefox bug)
  ]
}

function logOnDOMContentLoaded(details) {
  console.log("onDOMContentLoaded: " + details.url);
}

browser.webNavigation.onDOMContentLoaded.addListener(logOnDOMContentLoaded, filter);
```